# The windows will be always blocked after a http request in click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the situation below , my windows will be block always . how can i solve it ?

```js
$(obj).bind("click" , function(){
    var href = $(this).attr("url");
    $.ajax({
      url : login_Url ,
      type : "get" ,
      contentType : "json" ,
      success : function(data){
        if(data.status){
          
          //the window will be blocked
          window.open(href);            
          
        }
      }
    })
})
```

Comment: @VishnuShekhawat it is true by default

Comment: What exactly u mean by blocked? Does it freezes?

Comment: it was blocked by browser  and  told me “pop up a new window ,yes or no”  rather than just open the new window